# checking error while writing to a file

Tags: c++, file

I have

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename,ios::out | ios::app);
if(myfile.good()){ do smtg};

myfile.write(taskToWrite->buffer,taskToWrite->length);
```

Is there anyway to check if the write function doesn't work?
I'm checking before, with good(), but if I have an error while writing , how can I check it?
I couldn't understand what does the function returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `write` function returns the stream itself. So in your case, it will return a reference to `myfile`. The stream types are convertible to `bool` to check its failure status. So you can simply use this:

```
if (myfile.write(taskToWrite->buffer,taskToWrite->length)) {
  // Success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [std::ofstream::good()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) to check the state of the stream. If none of the error bits are set you can assume everything went well.